# Use LocalDateTime RequestParam in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, localdatetime

I have a problem when I try to use RequestParam with a LocalDateTime:

```
public ResponseData getTotalRevenue(@RequestParam(value = "startDate")
                                    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime startDate,
                                    @RequestParam(value = "endDate")
                                    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime endDate){
                        //....
            }
```

I test with this params :

```
/total-revenue?startDate=2022-07-28&endDate=2022-08-20
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: 
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime] 
for value '2022-07-28'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2022-07-28]]
```

Anyone can help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: Format you specified is - `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`, but the string you provide does not match it(your input is only a date). Required format and input format must match entirely.

Answer (score 0):

DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME is a format that expects date and time, but your request just includes the date. Try DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory:

> Parse attempt failed for value [2022-07-28]]

I think you want your `startDate` and `endDate` to be of type `LocalDate` and not `LocalDateTime` because you want to represent dates.

Anyway, you are passing the query parameters in wrong `DateTimeFormat`. Instead of `DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME`, you should use `DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE`.

```java
public ResponseData getTotalRevenue(@RequestParam(value = "startDate")
                                    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDateTime startDate,
                                    @RequestParam(value = "endDate")
                                    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDateTime endDate) {
    //....
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-web-modules/spring-mvc-java-2/src/main/java/com/baeldung/datetime/DateTimeController.java) is an example for your reference.

Look at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html) for all the ISO formats.